# Do Maxwell's equations (generalized) apply to _every_ $k$-form on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, hodge-theory, electromagnetism

> Given a pseudo-Riemannian $n$-manifold and a $k$-form $F$ on the manifold, I will call its exterior derivative $J=dF$ the *source* of $F$ and the differential $K=dG$ the *dual source* of $F$, where $G=​{\star}F$ is the Hodge dual of $F$.  Since $d\circ d=0$, the conservation laws $dJ=0$ and $dK=0$ follow. (EDIT: This is an obvious generalization of Maxwell's equations to arbitrary $n$, $k$ and metric tensor.)

Specialized to $n=4$ and $k=2$, and identifying $F$ as the electromagnetic 2-form (or rather, its dual), $J$ as the electric current 3-form and $K$ as the magnetic current 3-form, I have arrived at Maxwell's equations in general relativity as necessarily applying, including the associated conservation of electric and magnetic charge:

- $J=dF$ (the electric current 3-form is the source of the field)
- $K=d{\star}F$ (the magnetic current is the dual source of the field, though we observe that $K=0$)
- $dJ=0$ (conservation of electric charge)
- $dK=0$ (conservation of magnetic charge)

using standard mathematics from minimal assumptions:

- We assume a classical setting, as for general relativity, but generalized to any number of dimensions $n$.
- We assume that the field of interest can be described as a $k$-form.

My approach involves defining what the "source" and "dual source" of a field are, and then to show that these are what we call "charge", rather than the other way around.  Assuming that I have not made an error, the answer to the question in the title is yes (with a field's source being a $(k+1)$-form, and its dual source an $(n-k+1)$-form.  My question would then be:

> Why do we learn about electromagnetism as the consequence of innumerable observations (four different observational laws), rather than as the only possible form of the law aside from the non-existence of magnetic charge once we establish that the electromagnetic field is a $2$-form (which presumably follows from its transformation law established by measurement of the Lorentz force and special relativity)?

I have not needed to invoke anything like gauge theory, potentials, Lagrangians, symmetry – only standard theorems of differential geometry and Hodge theory.

Comment: Are you asking: Given $F$, let $J = dF$, $K = d*F$. Are $dJ = 0  = dK$?

Comment: @john: That follows trivially from $d^2=0$.  I am asking a meta question: what have I missed?  Why have I not seen this simple derivation of a mathematical generality used in physics, that shows that no other form of the equations is possible, but I see tedious derivations (in physics) involving unneeded assumptions?  I have this profound sense of disconnect: that physicists are ignoring maths.

Comment: I guess a natural question is how and why would you claim your equations are Maxwell's equations. You would need to somehow extract electric & magnetic vector field solutions from your equations to compare with experiment

Comment: @AloneAndConfused: see [Wikipedia - Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Relativistic_formulations), under "Differential forms".  My presentation of the equations differs as I said inasmuch as what I call $F$, they call ${\star}F$, though this has no significance in the context.

Comment: I agree for 2-forms it makes sense, but I was questioning calling your equations in terms of a arbitrary k-form "Maxwell's equations".

Comment: That is my generalization of the equations to apply to any $k$-form, and I guess I should have called them "a generalization of Maxwell's equations".  Only when $n=4$, $k=2$, the $k$-form would be the EM field, and I tried to make this clear under "Specialized to ...".

Comment: Okay. I suppose physicists may argue there is more to Maxwell's equations than just $dF=0$ and $d\star F=J$. The 2-form $F$ still needs to be decomposed into electric and magnetic fields, solutions found, EM stresses and forces due to the theory fpund etc

Comment: You seem to be trying to load more on the question than it is (which in effect is: "Why don't I ever see this simple derivation?").   Although I have thoughts for using the same approach for the stress-energy tensor and Lorentz forces, this is out of scope here.  The solutions for the standard case ($n=4$, $k=2$, Lorentzian metric) are the same because they are the same equations.

Comment: Agreed - but I *think* my "loading of the question" is precisely what physicists would care about, otherwise it is just a mathematical fact, as you have explained. Perhaps we are discussing it as cross purposes and I am also aware I am trying to argue about what I think a physicist would say!

Comment: But have you not missed the point?  I am trying to determine whether it being "just a mathematical fact" is generally recognized.  Perhaps this is not interesting to a mathematician (as trivially true); perhaps I should raise it in the physics forum.